# which is the more "versatile" haskell framework for web development?

Tags: web-applications, haskell, web, web-deployment

I want to start with the web development and I have some interest in Haskell.

I've seen there are so [many frameworks](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Frameworks)! I am not sure which is the better for me.

I am not asking which is the better framework, or which easy to use, or which is the best for newcomers (I don´t know anything about Haskell).

I want to know which is the best for all kinds of apps, the more "versatile".

Comment: Happstack, snap and yesod are the most "popular" in that list. It might be better to have a discussion about them on IRC, or google for blog posts comparing these frameworks. SO is better for concrete or specific questions.